# How do programatically change the attributes of <sj:tabbedpanel>

Tags: jquery-ui, struts2

I am using Struts jQuery plugin. Problem is with `<sj:tabbedpanel>`.
I want to preselect the tab depending on the input while loading the page.
I know there is property selectedTab="1".
But I want it to change it while loading the page using jQuery.
In jQuery-UI plugin, there is function `$("#tab").tabs('selected',2)` which does that.
What is the similar function which does the same thing here.

Comment: What is stopping you from calling `$("#tab").tabs('selected',2)`?

Comment: It doesn't work with tabbedpanel.. Don't know why..

Comment: And in plain jQuery it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="tabbed" selectedTab="%{selected}"></sj:tabbedpanel>
```

`selected` should be a parameter, which decides the opened tab.

If you still wanna use jQuery, please check the api: [jQuery Tabs API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs)

here is the important part:

```
A series of events fire when interacting with a tabs interface:

tabsselect, tabsload, tabsshow (in that order)
tabsadd, tabsremove
tabsenable, tabsdisable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from javascript then use `option` to set selected tab.

```
$("#tab").tabs( "option", "selected", 2);
```